# BottomNavigationView jumps up leaving blank space when fullscreen

Tags: java, android, fullscreen, bottomnavigationview

For a BottomNavigationView's last tab, I want the content to be below the status bar and make the status bar completely transparent. This works as expected but the **BottomNavigationView** jumps up leaving a blank space in the bottom when the last tab is selected.

There were similar topics in SO that said to set **fitWindowSystems** to **false**. I tried it, but it is not helping.

[image]

ExplorerFragment.java

```
public class ExplorerFragment extends Fragment {

    public ExplorerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
            window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.transparent));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            View decor = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
            decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explorer, container, false);
    }

}
```

fragment_explorer.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="com.orevon.fflok.fragments.ExplorerFragment"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <View android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="180dp"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          android:background="@drawable/splash_background4"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/mainBottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bottombar_bg"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_navigation"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, I did solve that problem somehow, don't remember how. Unfortunately, I can't help you right now since I've no access to that project anymore. You may open a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be useful for those who face a problem in the future.
I solved this issue just by adding

```
ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(view)
```

to my fragment's `onActivityCreated` method.
`view` - fragment's root view

in my case it looks like:

**KOTLIN**

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        view?.let {
            ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(it)
        }
    }
```

**JAVA**

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            View view = getView()
            if(view != null){
                ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(view)
            }
        }
```

**Update (6/27/2020):**
Since `onActivityCreated` method is deprecated on SDK >=29 you could use the code above inside `onViewCreated` method:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(view)
}
```

Comment: Where are you applying this? My Issue is when I come out of full screen mode Im also navigating to another fragment. when I arrive at the new fragment I have the bottom padding pushing the nav bar up.

Comment: I tried this, however , it does not work. Is there any solution to solve it ?

Answer (score 12):

The solution to the problem is setting the bottomNavigationView setOnApplyWindowsListener to null:

```
setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(null)
```

I struggled with this problem when implementing a bottom navigation view to my AR Core Sceneform fragment.

[Extra padding issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGzOL.png)

[Extra padding issue resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCnfA.png)

Comment: This is a life saver - thanks! For the record I'm using `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0-rc01`.

Comment: That works! It would be perfect if someone explained why it happens

Comment: This is the only thing that works in my case, but it feels like a workaround that can cause another issues :< Anyways, thank you!