# Proper way to switch fragments from stable to full-screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using a single activity - multiple fragment architecture with a bottom navigation bar. There are some fragments that use a stable layout flag, and others that use a fullscreen layout flag. However, when switching from SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE to SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN (and vice versa), the content doesn't fill the screen properly - when switching to stable, the bottom is pushed down past the navigation, and when switched back to fullscreen, the content doesn't fill the screen properly. If I switch to another fullscreen fragment from that one, the issue corrects itself. I wanted to know if there was a way to keep that issue from happening in the first place.

This is the code I'm using to switch between stable and fullscreen:

```
fun makeFullScreen() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
}

fun makeStable() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
}
```

The respective functions are being called in the onResume() function of each fragment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can see screenshots of the issue here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI6n8.jpg

Thanks

Edit 1: Just to clarify, I basically want it so that the bottom navigation bar stays in the right place at the bottom, rather than the "jumping" behavior you see in the screenshots.

Comment: Have you tried `activity.recreate()` when you make the switch, if nothing else works?

Comment: That's something that I think may work, the only thing is off the top of my head I'm not sure how to do it without ending up in an infinite loop. Though I only tried calling it directly from the fragment and not from the host activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a ton of searching (I've looked up this issue on and off for a few weeks now), I finally found something that works for me. The answer provided here: [BottomNavigationView jumps up leaving blank space when fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207843/bottomnavigationview-jumps-up-leaving-blank-space-when-fullscreen/53912959#53912959)

Comment: Where are you applying the kotlin code from the answer you linked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't seem to be helping with my issue. I also need the status bar to be displayed at all times.